# History and origin of sine function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing some research about the beginning of trigonometry. I want to know why and who draw the first time the sine function. Do you have one site or something that can help me ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry already contains  some interesting material

Comment: You should ask this at the [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site.

Comment: Maybe interesting: Trigonometric Delights by Eli Maor.

Answer (score 1):

In the anceint greek time they didn't use the sine, they used the chord instead which has $\text{crd}(\alpha)\in[0,2]$. The indians later took this and improved upon it and started using the sine instead which was roughly translated as "half-chord" because it's half the value of the chords value and half the angle.

Comment: Good answer.  Probably discovered by Brahmagupta around 630 CE:  $\text{chord}(\alpha) = \sqrt{2(1 - \cos \alpha)} = 2 \sin (\alpha/2)$.

Comment: Yepp that, thanks. I was just going from memory :)

Comment: thanks a lot but my research are about the begenning of the real sine function as f(x)= sin(x) etc

Comment: To know that you need its origin and why chord was not sufficient :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Astronomy and maybe in astrological predictions(curved planetary aspect/position). Shlokas had been devised for accurate calculations and used like trig table of values.

[AncientSine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jy%C4%81,_koti-jy%C4%81_and_utkrama-jy%C4%81)